# Setting active state for multi level menu items from Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for some help with modifying an existing function which controls the highlighted states of a multi level js accordion menu. I have had to use javascript due to certain css elements not working in safari browsers.

My problem is due to the multi level aspect as when a sub link is clicked, the parent link above it then deselects. I need the parent link to stay active when its sub links are clicked and only deselects when a link outside of that list is clicked upon.

I understand the theory of adding a conditional statement but simply don't know how to apply it correctly within the function...any help would be very much appreciated.

Here is the existing function which tells a link to be active or selected:

```
var Lst;

function CngClass(obj){
if (Lst) Lst.className='.topnav';
obj.className='selected';
Lst=obj;
}
```

and here is the menu code:

```
<ul class="topnav">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>

<li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">Top Link 2</a>
    <ul>
         <li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">Cookies</a></li>
         <li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">Events</a></li>
         <li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">Forms</a></li>
         <li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">Games</a></li>
         <li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">Images</a></li>
         <li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">Navigations</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">CSS</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">JQuery</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
         <li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">Tabs</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">Tutorials</a>
    <ul>
         <li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">HTML</a></li>
         <li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">CSS</a></li>
         <li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">JavaScript</a></li>
         <li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">Java</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">JSP</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">JSF</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">JPA</a></li>
                <li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
         <li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">Tabs</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">Contact</a></li>
<li><a onclick="CngClass(this);" href="#">Upload script</a></li>
```

Many thanks for any help or ideas...

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear, may I ask why you're not simply using JQuery? It simplifies your task so much more.
I've got a [live example](http://jsfiddle.net/zPqJF/10/) with JQuery (took me about 3 mins) you can try. I assume this is what you're trying to accomplish?

You can use the same method in normal javascript as well, except it's more work and probably less efficient.
The general idea is:

1. remove active class from the current `li`
2. find the 3rd parent from the clicked link (li, ul, li) and then apply the active class to
   that one instead.

Here's the JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".topnav li a").click(function(){

        //get the ul element
        var checkElement = $(this).next();
        if(checkElement.is('ul')) {
            //check if it's visible
            if(!checkElement.is(':visible')) {
                $(this).parent().addClass('opened');
                checkElement.slideDown();
            }else{
                $(this).parent().removeClass('opened');
                checkElement.slideUp();
            }
        }       

        //get the tree node
        var parentElement = $(this).parent().parent().parent();
        if(parentElement.is('li')){
            $(".topnav li.active").removeClass('active');
            parentElement.addClass('active');
        }
    });
});
```

Here's an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zPqJF/18/) where it highlights the li element you clicked.

Comment: Many thanks for your help here - this looks like it does what I need - the reason it ended up like this was simply a case of following tutorials that got me close to what I needed but as you can see it has become over complicated! Thanks for simplifying it!

Comment: No problem, before you commented I was working on a javascript version of the same thing, but I couldn't decide if I was going for the nodeTreeWalker or evaluate (which is pretty much what JQuery does). Either way, why reinvent the wheel, right?

Comment: Exactly! Thanks again for the input. I have just been looking at your live example though and have a question. I've seen that all the sub links become highlighted rather than just the one clicked on (and the parent link - e.g. 'Top Link 2' stays highlighted when 'Cookies' is clicked and is highlighted...but no others ) hope that makes sense?

Comment: I added another example to the original answer, at the bottom. Is that what you wanted? Examine the code, and it'll come to you. There's more documentation at [JQuery Documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page) if you're interested. The JQuery interface is easy to learn and easy to use. :)

Comment: This looks great, it will take a bit of familiarization but I'm sure this is the best way forward! Many thanks again for your help and suggestions!

Comment: Hi again, really sorry to ask again but it's still not actually doing what I need it to. Check out this fiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/pike800/zPqJF/31/) If you click 'Top Link 2', all the contained links (cookies, events etc) are active but none of them should be...Then if you click on 'cookies', the 'Top Link 2' deselects yet that should remain selected to indicate that you are in that section. Totally understand if you don't have time to offer any more help but thought I'd ask! Apologies again!